# Java - How to write a time stamp to a text file?

Tags: java

I'm making this Login bit to a larger program, and I want to save the time of when a failed login happens and save the timestamp to a file called FailedLogins.txt. The problem is,**"No suitable method found for write(Timestamp)**", when I put the time stamp variable in the fwriter.write().

```
try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("UserPass.txt"));
        fwriter = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("FailedLogins.txt"));

        if(ppassword.equals(rrepassword)) {

            writer.write("Name: " + ffname + " " + llname + "\n");
            writer.write("Email: " + eemail + "\n");
            writer.write("Password: " + ppassword + "\n\n");
        }
        else {
            password.setText("");
            repassword.setText("");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your passwords do not match.");

            //For Failed Logins text File
            Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
            fwriter.write(timestamp);
        }

    }
    catch ( IOException e) {
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if ( writer != null) {
                writer.close( );
            }
        }
        catch ( IOException e) {
        }
    }
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: have you tried timestamp.toString()?

Comment: What does the BufferedWriter API tell you?

Comment: As @johnII says, and also, have you overridden the `toString` method in that class? But in general it's not a great idea to use the output of `toString` for production code. Better to give TimeStamp a `public String createTimeStampString()` or something similar. Use `toString` more for debugging.

Comment: Side note: you're using the wrong `FileWriter` constructor if you want to append data to the file and not over-write the file.

Comment: Frankly, I think it's worth pointing out that logging passwords is a (imo) **bad idea**. And, did you consider writing the `currentTimeMillis`? Or using a `Date` and/or `DateTimeFormatter`?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want this one:

```
fwriter.write("" + timestamp.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.now().toString()
```

2018-01-06T22:33:12.123456Z

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

To get the current moment in UTC, call `Instant.now`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

### ISO 8601

Generate a string in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSSSSSSSZ

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

> 2018-01-06T22:33:12.123456Z

Now you can **pass that string to be written to your text file**. Always use ISO 8601 formats when serializing date-time values as text.

As you can see, the java.time classes use the ISO 8601 standard formats by default. No need to specify a formatting pattern.

Going the other direction.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2018-01-06T22:33:12.123456Z" ) ;
```

### File name

The colons are not allowed as a filename in some file systems such as [HFS+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus), so replace with another character. I suggest some character other than the hyphens used in the date portion, so that you may reconstruct the ISO 8601 format if ever needed.

```
String output = instant.toString().replace( ":" , "_" ) ;  // Replace colon with another character for compatibility across file systems.
```

> 2018-01-06T22_33_12.123456Z

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

java.io.Writer.write() method overloads only accepts following arguments,

```
public void write(int c) throws IOException {...}

public void write(char cbuf[]) throws IOException {...}

abstract public void write(char cbuf[], int off, int len) throws IOException;

public void write(String str) throws IOException {...}

public void write(String str, int off, int len) throws IOException {...}
```

Therefore you don't have facility to provide `Timestamp` object as its parameter.

Its is possible to provide following string representation of `Timestamp` object.

```
fwriter.write(timestamp.toString());
// Or
fwriter.write(timestamp + "");
```